# Different results from STRREAD() for reading strings

Tags: arrays, matlab, date

I have a date cell array which is read from a csv file. The format is below:

date =

'2008.12.01'

'2008.12.02'

'2008.12.03'

'2008.12.04'

'2008.12.05'
... ...

And I want to:

1. turn the cell array to a string array,
2. use the strread() to read its "yyyy","mm" and "dd" value into 3 double array [year,mm,dd],
3. use the datenummx() to turn [year,mm,dd] into date seriel num.

After i use

> > date = char(date);

the date array become like this:

date =

2008.12.01

2008.12.02

2008.12.03

2008.12.04

2008.12.05
... ...

which I think the result is what i want...

But after I use the strread(), it gives me odd result.

> > [year,month,day]=strread(date,'%d%d%d','delimiter','.');

year =

```
-1

 0

 0

 0

 0
```

... ...

BUT if I use the code below, the strread() can give me the right answer:

> > s = sprintf('2008.12.01')

s =

2008.12.01

> > [year,month,day]=strread(s,'%d%d%d','delimiter','.')

year =

```
    2008
```

month =

```
12
```

day =

```
 1
```

And I checked in the matlab that both the "date" and "s" is a char array.(by using function 'ischar' and simply display both)...

But why do the strread() give differnt results?

Can anyone answer?

by the way, I use the MatLab v6.5.(for my own reason, so please don't comment by asking "why not use a higher version")....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
date = char(date);
```

It does not create an array of strings, there is no array of strings in matlab. It creates an array of chars. As you already noticed, your `strread`-line is fine if you input a single date, so input each date form your original cell array individually:

```
for idx=1:numel(date)
    [year(idx),month(idx),day(idx)]=strread(date{idx},'%d%d%d','delimiter','.');
end
```

Preallocation of year, month and day improves the performance.

Comment: Thanks,Daniel...and I wondering is there a way that I can perform the loop without "for"? I heard that it's really slow when treat a large amount of data.

Comment: And also, I am wondering if the 'strread' cannot accept a char array as input, why don't it return **ERROR** instead of give an odd result?

Comment: I have no experience with the performance of such old Matlab versions. Use preallocation and test it.

Comment: Regarding your second commend: `strread` can process matrices of chars, but it processes column-wise. This results in numbers to large to fit into a double (probably causing the -1) and a lot of `0` because there is nothing between the `.`